# Line break in X axis label with spaces between two words in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have a requirement to break the x axis label in multiple lines if it has a space between two words as the real time category labels are big names and I have to show it in small chart.

So with the given example. I want to see Akash and then in the next line it should show Jain.
I am using the below code to plot the waterfall chart.

```
source('./r_files/flatten_HTML.r')
library("plotly")
 dataset <- data.frame(Category = c("Akash Jain","Ankit Jain","Pankaj Jain","Nitin Pandey","Gopal Pandit","Ramnath Agarwal"),
                      TH =  c(-62,-71,-1010,44,-44,200))
#dataset <- data.frame(Category = Values$Category, TH = Values$TH)
#dataset <- as.data.frame(cbind(Values$Category,Values$TH))
dataset$Category = dataset$Category
dataset$TH = dataset$TH
dataset$SortedCategory <- factor(dataset$Category, levels = dataset$Category)
dataset$id <- seq_along(dataset$TH)
dataset$type <- ifelse(dataset$TH > 0, "in",   "out")
dataset$type <- factor(dataset$type, levels = c("out", "in"))
dataset$end <- cumsum(dataset$TH)
dataset$start <- c(0, head(dataset$end, -1))
Hover_Text <- paste(dataset$SortedCategory, "= ", dataset$TH, "<br>")
dataset$colors <- ifelse(dataset$type =="out","red","green")
g <- plot_ly(dataset, x = ~SortedCategory, y = ~start, type = 'bar', marker = list(color = 'rgba(1,1,1, 0.0)'), hoverinfo = 'text') %>%
  add_trace(y = dataset$TH , marker = list(color = ~colors), hoverinfo = "text", text = Hover_Text  ) %>%
  layout(title = '',
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = ""),
         barmode = 'stack',
         showlegend = FALSE) 

g
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Akash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert line breaks for each space in your `SortedCategory` and then generate your plot:

```
dataset$SortedCategory <- sapply(dataset$SortedCategory, function(x) gsub(" ", " <br> ", x))
```